# Modal pop up one time per user

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, jquery-cookie

In my website, I am using a simple modal popup with some input controls ( name, email, button).
The purpose of modal popup is:

- After filling all mandatory fields, if user press "submit" button they will get one .pdf file.
- I launch the modal upon onload.

**Here, I am trying to do:**

1. Open the modal popup only once for a user, or
2. Don't want to show the modal popup to users who previously filled out the form already

**Here is the code of my modal popup:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#eBookModal").modal('show');
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="eBookModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <div class="row">
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Download eBook</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" id="eBookform" class="contact-form"
                      action="file.pdf">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text" name="FName" autocomplete="off" id="eBook_FName" placeholder="First Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text" name="LName" autocomplete="off" id="eBook_LName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-text" name="email" autocomplete="off" id="eBook_email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="eBook_download">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn main-btn" style="color:#fff !important;">Download Now</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your code? Post the code you have so far.

Comment: @WebDevBooster, i added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep record of the modal displays. To store that info, you can either use a [`cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Based on the stored value, you can decide whether to show the modal or not.

The sample below uses the `localStorage` as an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Check if user saw the modal
    var key = 'hadModal',
        hadModal = localStorage.getItem(key);

    // Show the modal only if new user
    if (!hadModal) {
        $('#eBookModal').modal('show');
    }

    // If modal is displayed, store that in localStorage
    $('#eBookModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        localStorage.setItem(key, true);
    })
});
```

Available as a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/goZVYe) too.

If you would like to hide the modal just from those who already submitted the form, you should set the flag upon form submit, like so:

```
$('#eBookform').on('submit', function (event) {
    // event.preventDefault();// depending on your use case
    localStorage.setItem(key, true);
})
```

Note: to reset the stored value, just call `localStorage.removeItem('hadModal')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just to show the modal one time for first time visit and previous code didn't work try this !

```
$(window).load(function(){    
var Modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); 
var key = 'hadModal',
hadModal = localStorage.getItem(key);

if (!hadModal) {
    Modal.style.display = "block";
    localStorage.setItem(key, true);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("ModalShown=true")<0) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                   
                    $("#homepageModal").addClass("modal-show")
                }, 1000);
        });
        var date = new Date(),
            expires = 'expires=';
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        expires += date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = 'ModalShown=true ;' + expires + '; path=/';
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you get this script to work in Bootstrap 5 without using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Check if user saw the modal
var key = 'hadModal',
    hadModal = localStorage.getItem(key);

// Show the modal only if new user
if (!hadModal) {
    $('#eBookModal').modal('show');
}

// If modal is displayed, store that in localStorage
$('#eBookModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    localStorage.setItem(key, true);
})
```

});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).